# C# - LoadLibrary fails with 32bit DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, dll

I've got a C# application which loads a DLL at runtime. The DLL is 32bit, so it is the application.

I tried with the LoadLibrary from:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

but without result; it always return `IntPtr.Zero`. I tried also using

```
[DllImport("%windir%\\SysWOW64\\kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
    [DllImport("%windir%\\SysWOW64\\kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
    [DllImport("%windir%\\SysWOW64\\kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

but this way the application gets a "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" exception when calling LoadLibrary.

Did anyone met this issue before?

Comment: Use `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]` then when your `LoadLibrary` result is `IntPtr.Zero` look at the result of `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` for the reason.

Comment: Can you try to call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @AlexK., the error code is 0x000000c1

Comment: That's ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT so you are trying to load a 32 bit library into a 64 bit process.

Comment: It sounds, like your application is compiled for a 32-bit platform as well. Please clarify your environment. If your question is: How do I load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process, however, the answer is simple: You can't.

Comment: Lesson: don't neglect error checking.

Comment: Actually, I wrote "The DLL is 32bit, so it is the application." My application is compiled with "Any_Cpu" target, I also tried to dumpbin it and the result is that it is 32 bit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am not neglecting error checking; I check for the result and it is a zeroPtr, so nothing is loaded. I just tried some other ways to get it working but it seems like there are not.

Comment: Make sure you understand the *Any CPU* [compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/platform-compiler-option). Since you didn't specify your compiler or .NET version, also read up on the changes regarding that option in VS 2012/.NET 4.5.

Comment: I'll read about that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your C# exe have to be compiled to 32bit.

Check this page for error code detail:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

> ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT
>   193 (0xC1)
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: I will try to recompile my application under x86 target insted of "AnyCPU" and see if that way it works.

Comment: Even with x86 as target the loading fails, same error 0xC1 when trying to load the DLL

Comment: 1. You do not have to specify path of `kernel32.dll`, just `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]` should be ok

Comment: 2. You have to compile your exe to 32bit by setting `Platform target` to `AnyCPU with Prefer 32-bit` or `x86` in `Build` page of project property window

Comment: 3. You have to make sure your dll is a valid 32bit PE format dll

Comment: 4. The exception of `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` usually occurred while parsing xaml resource which presents a window definition, custom control, custom style or template or something that can be described in xaml, and it must be occurred in managed code, that means, the exception is not directly thrown by `LoadLibrary`. So, maybe there're some other detail you ignored in your code, you have to find out the exact point where the exception was thrown first.